# CSS:Why are my HTML elements somehow relatively positioned?

Tags: html, css

By relative positioned, I mean when **height-wise**, when I try to add a header, the other elements below will get'pushed down'.

```js
document.querySelector(".toggler").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  this.parentElement.classList.toggle("up");
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.box{
  height:100%;
  widows: 100%;
  background-image:url('http://tombricker.smugmug.com/Travel/San-Francisco-California/i-jk2Z7D7/0/L/san-francisco-golden-gate-bridge-morning-sun-bricker-L.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slide{
  background:red;
  height:77vh;
  width:55vw;
  
  position:relative;
  left:38vw;
  
  transform:translateY(100vh);
  transition:transform 0.4s ease-out;
}
.toggler{
  /*triangle button*/
  position:absolute;
  top:-3vh;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  border-left: 27.5vw solid transparent;
  border-right:27.5vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3vh solid white;
}
/*See JS for 'up' is used.*/
.slide.up{
  transform:translateY(23vh);
}
.slide.up .toggler{
  transform:translateY(3vh) rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='slide up'>
    <span class='toggler'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you try to type in some word in DIV with class='box', the red rectangle slider will get pushed down, even though the two elements aren't even touching.

The word you type in that DIV right before the DIV inside it with class="slide up", will get display in the result at the upper lefthand corner.

I spent a long time trying to figure out what is wrong.I couldnt.

**EDIT-1**: This problem is not JS related. I deleted the JS code, the problem still there.

**EDIT-2**: I change the CSS 'position' on .slide class from  relative to absolute. And although it didn't work, the result is a bit different. With RELATIVE, when I try adding the header, the rectangle get push down but you cannot scroll down to see the rest of it. With ABSOLUTE, you can scroll down to see the hidden part of the rectangle. I don't know why it is. I have overflow:hidden on .box.

Comment: the `this` in `this.parentElement` is not going to do what you think it'll do. Use `event.target.parentElement`, because `this` in global context (which is the context that a DOM event is fired off  in) is the global context (i.e. `window`)

Comment: Many times the perceived weirdness of JavaScript can be understood (a little) more clearly simply by using `console.log(this)`.

Comment: The problem still exist even without JS.

Answer (score 0):

`position:relative;` is different from `position:absolute`: It still keeps the element in the document flow. `relative`just means you can move it away from it's default position (which is the same as when you use "static") using parameters like `top` or `left`. But it's still in the document flow, and when you add content to its container above it, it is moved.

If you want an element that doesn't do that, use `position:absolute`.

Comment: Do you mean the position relative for .slide? I changed it to absolute. But still the red rectangle get pushed down.